# Display an image on the X-Z plane (instead of the default X-Y)

Tags: image, matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axes

I can get an image plot on the X-Y plane using `imagesc`, but now I would like to have it on the X-Z plane for further usage. Is there any way to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [`surface`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface.html) instead of `imagesc`:

```
INPUT = [3,4,5
         4,5,6];
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
figure(); 
ZZ = padarray(INPUT,[1 1],0,'post'); % See note #2
[XX,YY] = meshgrid((1:size(INPUT,2)+1)-0.5,(1:size(INPUT,1)+1)-0.5);
% imagesc
subplot(3,1,1); imagesc(INPUT); xlim([0 4]); ylim([0.5 2.5]);
view([-50 50]); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z'); grid on;
title('imagesc');
% Normal (X-Y):
subplot(3,1,2); surface(XX,YY,0*XX,ZZ,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','flat'); 
view([-50 50]); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z'); axis ij; box on; grid on;
title('X-Y surface'); caxis([min(INPUT(:)),max(INPUT(:))]);
% Rotated (X-Z):
subplot(3,1,3); surface(XX,0*ZZ,YY,ZZ,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','flat');
view([-50 50]); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z'); axis ij; box on; grid on;
title('X-Z surface'); caxis([min(INPUT(:)),max(INPUT(:))]);
```

#### Several notes:

1. You might need to `flipud` or `fliplr` some of the inputs in the 2<sup>nd</sup> `surface` plot (depending on how you define the `Y -> Z` transition).
2. Presentation-wise the output is the same, **but**, if you try to compare the values of the nodes you will not get the same result between the `X-Y` and the `imagesc` outputs. The reason for this is that the surface is defined using the vertices, and an Image object is defined using the value in the center of each square.

**Output:**

[image: Comparison of outputs]

Comment: @dinex Make another permutation of the 1st 3 inputs: `XX,YY,0*ZZ` => `YY,0*ZZ,XX` => `0*ZZ,XX,YY :)`

Comment: @Dev-iL But if my input matrix is like [3,4,5;4,5,6], is it still possible to use your code to draw?